# How to create a long time in Milliseconds from String in Java 8 with LocalDateTime?

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-time

I have an input date in format `yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS` and convert it to long this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
                   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try {
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(lapTime);
    time = date.getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And, after some manipulation, get `mm:ss.SSS` back from long:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");
return simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(time));
```

How to change my old style code to Java8?
I looked at `LocalDateTime` and `Instant` classes, but don't know how to use them properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What did your search turn up? In which was it insufficient or failed? We can help you much more precisely from such context. [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: Ask your self once more whether you want to keep the millisecond count around. I’d keep the `LocalDateTime` instead and never need the millis (or maybe a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` to define a point in time). While a `LocalDateTime` tells you that it is a date and time, a `long` is low-level and tells you nothing about what the value signifies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with input formatted date and then convert into [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) with zone to extract epoch timestamp

```
String date = "2019-12-13_09:23:23.333";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
         DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS");

long mills = LocalDateTime.parse(date,formatter)
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toInstant()
                .toEpochMilli();

System.out.println(mills);
```

Comment: I try your solution, but it did not match previous calculation. For example earlier I recieve 1527152472434 and now it is 1527152472, therewhy I think here SSS were lose

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime
.parse(
    "2019-12-13_09:23:23.333".replace( "_" , "T" )
)
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) 
)
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

## ISO 8601

Your input string is close to compliance with the standard ISO 8601 formats used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

To fully comply, simple replace the underscore `_` I. The middle with a uppercase `T`.

```
String input =  "2019-12-13_09:23:23.333".replace( "_" , "T" ) ;
```

Parse without needing and formatter.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Assign the time zone intended for this date and time. Did the publisher of that data intend 9 AM in Tokyo Japan on that date, or did they mean 9 AM in Toledo Ohio US? Those would be two different moments several hours apart.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract an `Instant` to adjust into UTC. Interrogate for the count of milliseconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
long milliseconds = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```