# how to convert long value to java.util.Date in timezone EST?

Tags: java, datetime

How to convert a long value to Date object in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" (in timezone EST). I am looking for the solution the other way around: convert a long value to Date Object.

Using Java 7.

Comment: is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329786/how-to-create-a-long-time-in-milliseconds-from-string-in-java-8-with-localdateti/59330041#59330041 ?

Comment: @Deadpool, thanks for your quick reply, I am looking for the solution the other way around: convert a long value to Date Object. (And I should add that I am on java 7).

Comment: show the code that you have tried ?

Comment: Have you tried using the constructor public Date(long date) described at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)? (and then use SimpleDateFormat, which is in java 7 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long))

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Yes, they work on Java 7. Add [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project and you’re flying. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java convert millisecond timestamp to date with respect to given timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714322/java-convert-millisecond-timestamp-to-date-with-respect-to-given-timezone)

Comment: Thanks everybody who commented or edited this post. Sorry, i was in a hurry, my question was likely ambiguous. I will remember to ask questions clearer, hopefully with sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach should work even in java 7.

```
Date d = new Date(1527152472);//pass in whatever long value you have to the date constructor
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//sets the format you want
TimeZone etTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(etTimeZone);// sets the time zone of the formatter
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(d));//gives the formatted date
```

references:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)
[shows date constructor with long argument in java 7 -- not deprecated]

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html [shows SimpleDateFormat in java 7]

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/convert-date-time-to-est-est5edt/
[I used the approach for Java version < 8. See there for an extended discussion about America/New_York versus getTimeZone("EST") which might be more what you want -- but according to the author there, probably not]

Comment: Thanks for help, yours was the closest I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
new Date().setTime( milliseconds )
```

## `java.util.Date::setTime`

> I am looking for the solution the other way around: convert a long value to Date Object

Assuming by "a long value" you mean a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC:

```
java.util.Date d = new Date() ;
d.setTime( millis ) ;
```

## `org.threeten.bp.Instant`

The [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class is terrible, and is now legacy. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically replaced by the `java.time.Instant` class.

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 & Java 7, use the back-port library, [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

```
org.threeten.bp.Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millis ) ;
```

Convert to a `java.util.Date` if you must interoperate with old code.

```
java.util.Date d = org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toDate( instant ) ;
```

Vice versa.

```
org.threeten.bp.Instant instant = org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toInstant( d ) ;
```

## Strings

As for…

> Date object in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" (in timezone EST)

…date-time objects do not have a “format”. They can produce text representing their internal value in various formats. But the strings they produce, or parse, are distinct and separate from the date-time objects.

As for "timezone EST", there is no such thing. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

I will assume that by "EST" you meant some time zone such as `America/Montreal` or `America/New_York`.

```
org.threeten.bp.ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
```

Apply that zone to our `Instant` to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generating a string representing part of the internal value of that `ZonedDateTime` object. Your desired format shows the date and the time but omits any mention of the zone or offset. I do *not* recommend omitting the zone/offset as the reader may misunderstand and assume the wrong zone.

We can use the predefined formatter [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) to get us close to your desired format. This formatter produces text in standard ISO 8601 format. The standard specifies a `T` between the date and time portions. We can replace that `T` with a SPACE to get your desired format.

```
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ;
String output = 
        zdt
        .format( f )
        .replace( "T" , " " ) 
;
```

If you want to hide the fractional second, you could truncate. The *java.time* classes use immutable objects, so a fresh `ZonedDateTime` object will be instantiated. Your original `ZonedDateTime` object will *not* be altered.

```
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ;
String output = 
        zdt
        .truncatedTo( org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS )  // Drops the fractional second, producing a new fresh `ZonedDateTime` object.
        .format( f )
        .replace( "T" , " " ) 
;
```

Instead of this manipulations, you could define a custom formatting pattern. Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered many times already.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks for your comments and editing, unfortunately, I cannot pick multiple best answers, yours was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the long value? If you get the thime with [System.currentTimeMillis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) it should be im UTC. You can create a new Date object with the long value and use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559165/converting-date-from-utc-to-est-in-java#8559246) to convert it to EST

To format the date you can use SimpleDateFormat

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.